# np.array to a function in python - 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to eliminate some values from the present list but not getting an idea where I'm going wrong.

I have just started exploring Jupyter with python for data science. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Q Write a function that takes a NumPy array (of any shape and size), and two clipping values, call range_min and range_max. Any values in the input greater than range_max should be clipped to be equal to range_max, and any values less than range_min should be clipped to be equal to range_min.

```py
    def clip_array_range(array, range_min, range_max):
        if array[val] < range_min:
            return range_min
        if array[val] > range_max:
            return range_max
        return array[val] 

    a = np.array([-3, 2, 3, 5, 22, -12, -8, 2, 10, 38, 15])
    a_clipped = clip_array_range(a, -10, 10)
    print(a_clipped)
    # expected result: [ -3   2   3   5  10 -10  -8   2  10  10  10]     

    a = np.array([100, -100, 50, -50]).reshape(2,2)
    a_clipped = clip_array_range(a, -10, 10)
    print(a_clipped)
    # expected result: [[10 -10][10,-10] 2X2 array`
```

The error is

```py
     a = np.array([-3, 2, 3, 5, 22, -12, -8, 2, 10, 38, 15])       
     a_clipped = clip_array_range(a, -10, 10)
     print(a_clipped)
     # TypeError -list object is not callable
```

Comment: Something is trying treat a list as a function.  Or more likely you have mistakenly  changed a function into a list.  You need to identify the problem variable. We can't reproduce it from the code that you have given us.

Comment: The second section of code is an error part don't include it in the code.                     An error on this line a = np.array([-3, 2, 3, 5, 22, -12, -8, 2, 10, 38, 15])

Comment: Naming a variable `array` might be overwriting `np.array`

Comment: np.array is an attribute of the NumPy module. we can pass the array as an argument to a function and just for a correction, I changed "array" name to "a"  in clip_array_range  function. It's still showing the same error.

Comment: What is the type of the problem variable?

Answer (score 1):

Write this -

```
def clip_array(a, min, max):
    a[a > max] = max
    a[a < min] = min
    return a

a = np.array([-3, 2, 3, 5, 22, -12, -8, 2, 10, 38, 15])
a = clip_array(a, -10, 10)
```